# PHP and MySQL Runs twice but only echos once

Tags: php, mysql

I'm troubleshooting a problem on my site and I have narrowed it down to the php being run twice. I assume this means the page is loaded twice but the catch is that the code is only echoed or printed once. I figured this out using ChromePHP to log some text. That text prints in the console twice every now and again.

The main issue is that I'm making a mysql query and setting a variable. In an example. It prints the ID number it gets as 2, but then the code randomly loads again and that variable is now set to something else... lets say 15 or whatever. But visually the echoed variable is still 2.

```
include 'php/classes/ChromePhp.php';
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname );

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if ($result = mysqli_query($link,'SELECT questionID FROM questions order by rand() limit 1')) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    printf("Question ", $row['questionID']);
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    ChromePhp::log('QUESTIONID '.$row['questionID']);
}       
if($link) 
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

I've looked around and people say it could be the favicon being loaded separately or the .htaccess redirect which I use. I took the .htaccess off and I still have this issue.

Any pointers to a direction would be nice.

Thanks

Comment: ...and if you remove the `echo` statement on your penultimate line do neither 2 nor 15 get printed?

Comment: For your own safety and welfare you should really not be using the deprecated and dangerous `mysql_query` interface. [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) or `mysqli` are considerably easier to use properly.

Comment: Does your page display additional HTML besides `H1` tag you posted in your code?

Comment: I updated this page to use mysqli and I still get the same issue. I used to have more HTML but I have reduced the code to this so I can find the issue. What you see is what you get.

Comment: there. Its as stripped down as I can get it. I've been programming this site for months now and this is the first time I've seen this.

Comment: ok it has nothing to do with mysql or my html code. i reduced it to simply

`<?php
include 'ChromePhp.php';
ChromePhp::log('text ');
?>`

and it still logs text twice in the console. So i feel like it has something to do with my server

Answer (score 0):

I discovered it was a Google Chrome Extension: FirePHP that was causing the reload of code. Once I deleted the extension everything started working again!